# Azure DevOps link release pipeline to deployment group

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I am working with a self-hosted agent to release code into a target on-prem server. In my case, I just want to copy a file from the artifacts directory (.exe file) into a folder on my machine. So I created a deployment group and installed the on-prem agent on this server. I created the release pipeline...but since I am just copying a file, I couldn't use one of the predefined templates. So I started with Empty Job. Then I added a step to copy the file using the "Copy Files" step. However, no where in this process is there a place to associate a deployment group. Some of the pre-defined templates have the option to specify the deployment group. But in an empty job with an added step, how do I specify the deployment group? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a Deployment Group Job in the Tasks section of the pipeline. Originally I was using the default Task which was running on a Microsoft agent. So was able to delete that one and add a Deployment Group job.